# Div with <a> tag

Tags: css, html

First of, I know there are many similar questions to this, but none of the articles I have read has helped me. Somehow this won't work..

I want to make the area inside the `class="downloadBoks"` to be clickable, and not just the text within `<a></a>`. Not using JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<div class="sideboks">
    <div class="downloadBoks">
        <a href="Prosjektplan.pdf">Prosjektbeskrivelse</a>
    </div>
    <div class="downloadBoks">
        <a href="Statusrapport.pdf">Statusrapport</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.downloadBoks {
    height: 23px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    line-height: 25px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0 2px 2px #777777;
}


div.sideboks{
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 54px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #B7AFA3;
    border:solid;
    border-width: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0px 0px #777777;
}
```

This is the code I have so far. Right now the "downloadBoks" is purely looks.

edit: So I realised that having the div, within another div might have something to do with it? So updated with that code as well. Thanks for all the responses so far!

Comment: Purely looks? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.downloadBoks a {
     display: block;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

This will make the entire square clickable. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pn5Sj/3/)

Comment: I'd recommend setting height and width to 100% as well.

Comment: The `a` element inherits height and width from the parent. See demo.

Comment: Still doesn't work, the downloadBoks is located inside another div, does this have something to say?

Comment: I didn't know it would have anything to say, but I'll edit, sec:) 
I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5, you can put blocks in `a` tags:

```
<a href="Prosjektplan.pdf">
    <p class="downloadBoks">
        Prosjektbeskrivelse
    </p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `<a>` inside of the div's have 100% height and width. This way they take all the interior of the div and thus the div is "clickable":

```
.downloadBoks a
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```